# Retrofit 2.x.x + Okhttp3 intercepter + Dagger +Rx - Connection not closed

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, rx-android, okhttp

I'm using 
Retrofit 2.2.0 + okhttp3 Intercepter + GSONConverterFactory (Dagger2)+ RxJava2.

When checking on the server, it seem like the connection made by the app is kept alive, and not closed even after response is received.

So basically I have

App module - Where Retrofit with GSONCOnverterFactory and okhttp client and it's interceptor is present.

App Module class :

```
@Singleton
@Provides
protected MyService providesMyService(@Named("MyService") Retrofit retrofit) {
    return retrofit.create(MyService.class);
}

@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("MyService")
protected Retrofit providesMyRetrofit(GsonConverterFactory factory) {

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    builder.connectTimeout(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    builder.readTimeout(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    builder.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
    builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new CachingControlInterceptor());

    //caching 
    builder.cache(MyCache.getCache());

    builder.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .setLevel(loggingLevel));
    try {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(builder.build())
                .addConverterFactory(factory)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

My Interceptor :

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    final String userPassword = USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD;

    Request original = chain.request();
    Request request = original.newBuilder()
            .header("User-Agent", SOME_AGENT)

            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(userPassword.getBytes(UTF8)), UTF8))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .header("Keep-Alive", "timeout = 3")
            .method(original.method(), original.body())
            .build();


    Response response = chain.proceed(request);


    return response;
}
```

this is Rx Code :

```
 MyApp.getInstance().getAppComponent()
            .getMyService()
            .getData(queryMap, resultValues)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe((MyResponse myResponse) -> {

               //success result handled here
            }, throwable -> {
                //exception result handled here
            });
```

I don't see any warning in code or in logcat. Passing Keep-Alive : timeout in header is not helping too.

How can I verify from the app side if connection is closed properly, or if it is kept open even after the response is received on the app ?

Comment: I'd assume that if a terminal event on the Rx chain occurs then it's resources are released - can you confirm `onComplete`, `onError` or `onSuccess` (if using single) is called.

Comment: @mark keen Yes.  I'm getting correct response and I'm able to proceed

Comment: How about setting [`ConnectionPool`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2031#issuecomment-159214485)? The function, that you could you to pint to your code is [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#connectionPool-okhttp3.ConnectionPool-)

Comment: I'm confused... what do you expect to happen? You set a ``Keep-Alive`` of 3000 seconds which is almost 1 hour (50 minutes) and want the connection to be closed? But isn't the purpose of a persistent connection to stay alive so you can send multiple requests and responses through the same channel? Sorry for the pool of questions, I'm not an expert in http, just want to understand.

Comment: @DavidRawson that's old SDK. In new SDK SDK does that.

Comment: @Fred timeout = 3000 indicates 3000 ms not 3000s

Comment: @R.Zagórski I don't see any connection pool being used here.

Comment: @NayaneshGupte according to this it's in seconds: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive Hence my confusion

Comment: @Fred tried changing timeout to timeout = 5 but no use.